# web browser not found the copied file

Tags: c#, browser

I have a data grid view contain details from xml files and I have a web browser to show the xml file.
I want to show the xml files with spicily style, so I created folder "Logs with format" contain xsl and css files and temp directory. And I copy all xml file to temp directory, to show him from there.

The problem: the web browser not success to open the copied file because "the path is incorrect" (and it's not true).
This the code I wrote, the file copied successfully:

```
string logPath = "";
logPath = dg_autoTestStatus.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

// copy the log to tempore folder to show the log with style
File.Copy(logPath, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Logs with format\temp\temp.xml", true);
// file copied successfully (filename changed to temp.xml)!!

try
{
    Uri path = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Logs with format\temp\temp.xml");
    wb_logs.Url = path;
    // ERROR I GET: Cannot find..... Make sure the path or Internet address is correct
}
catch (Exception) {}
```

Maybe someone know what I do wrong? (Why I get this error: "Cannot find..... Make sure the path or Internet address is correct")?

Comment: I am guessing, are you wanting to open a file, for example: file:///temp.xml.  could you update your question to show what the value of path is?

Comment: @miltonb: Yes, I want to open the copied file with web browser

Comment: I think to solve your problem you need to focus on the format of the path variable.

Comment: @miltonb: how to do this?

Comment: What I would do is set a breakpoint on the wb_logs line and get the actual value of path' cut n paste into a browser window I already have open. Then check that is actually what you expect.

Comment: it seems like IE know to read 4 backslash...

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` finish with \\
So when I add `@\Logs` to the string it's become `debug\\\\Logs`.

The solution is to add my directory without `\`, like this:

```
File.Copy(logPath, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Logs with format\temp\temp.xml", true);
try
{
    Uri path = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Logs with format\temp\temp.xml");
    wb_logs.Url = path;
}
```

Anyway, Thank you!